# Choose $k$ numbers from $n$ numbers and what is the probability that they are divisible by given number $q$?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I have $n$ numbers (from $1$ to $n$). I choose $k$ numbers from these. So I need to calculate the probability that these $k$ numbers are divisible by given number $q$.

Comment: With or without replacement?

Comment: Without replacement.

Answer (score 4):

Without loss of generality we may assume that $q$ is positive.

There are $\dbinom{n}{k}$ equally likely ways to choose $k$ numbers from $n$.

There are $m=\lfloor n/q\rfloor$ of our numbers that are divisible by $q$. (Here $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer which is $\le x$.)

So there are $\dbinom{m}{k}$ "favourable" outcomes.

Our probability is therefore $\dfrac{\binom{m}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}$.